# Don't show messengers in div

Tags: jquery, html

I made `registration.php` and `login.php` pages with 100% working codes. I did to show code in div when I click link (using jquery).
Everythink work perfect , but it don't show messengers when registration is completed/failed or login is completed/failed (it don't show messenger nowhere).

**jQuery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#testb').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var page_url = $(this).prop('href');
      $('#test').load("registration.php");
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<a id="testb" href="registration.php">Registration</a>
<br>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

How can I make it to show messengers in the div when `registration/login` is completed/failed

Comment: What are "messengers"? Your question is a tad confusing -- could you please clarify? : )

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you included the code for registration.php

Comment: I believe he means messages. Warning if failed and confirmation if succeeded.

Comment: Yes I mean this warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're making the ajax call, you can add code to execute when it completes successfully and code to execute when it fails.  An example is below:

```
$('#testb').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var page_url = $(this).prop('href');
  $('#test').load("registration.php",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
      if(statusTxt=="success") {
          alert("External content loaded successfully!");
      }
      if(statusTxt=="error") {
          alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
      }
  });
});
```

See the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp) page for further reference.